# Arten von Adjektiven

Tags: grammar, english-to-german, adjective

In einem englischen Paper über deutsche Sprache wird von "**attributive and descriptive adjectives**" gesprochen.

In meinem Grammatik Duden (Band 4 - 7 Auflage) steht, dass es folgende Arten von Adjektiven gibt:

- qualifizierende Adjektive
- relationale Adjektive
- quantifizierende Adjektive
- adjektivisch gebrauchte Partizipien

Weiter steht, dass folgende Gebrauchsweisen vorkommen:

- attributiver Gebrauch
- substantivierter (nominalisierter) Gebrauch
- prädikativer Gebrauch
- adverbialer Gebrauch

Mit "attributive adjectives" sind wohl attributive Adjektive gemeint.
Was ist mit "descriptive adjectives" gemeint? Ich würde es mit beschreibend / qualifizierende Adjektive gleichsetzen. Ist das korrekt?

Dementsprechend würde "attributive and descriptive adjectives" für mich "attributive und qualifizierende Adjektive" bedeuten. Ist das richtig?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ja. In der Phrase "ein großer Baum" ist *groß* ein attributives, qualifizierendes Adjektiv.
Also ein ganz normales Eigenschaftswort.

Es versieht dem Baum mit einer Eigenschaft - es qualifiziert ihn.
Lateinisch  *qualis* = wie beschaffen?

Comment: In deinem ersten Beispiel ist groß "attributiv und gleichzeitig qualifizierend". Mir ist gerade leider nicht klar, ob attributiv und qualifizierend immer zusammen auftritt, oder ggf. auch getrennt. Meinem Duden-Verständnis nach, ist dies nur eine Kombinationsmöglichkeit. Wenn ich nun schreiben will, was die Autoren in dem Paper gemacht haben, ist dann "Sie konzentrieren sich auf attributive und qualifizierende Adjektive" korrekt? Oder eher "... qualifizierende Adjektive und Adjektive mit attributivem Gebrauch"?

Comment: @InterestedUser Attributiv und qualifizierend sind zwei Paar Schuhe. Das eine (attributiv) besagt, dass es als Attribut verwendet wird. "Der Baum ist groß" beispielsweise hat kein attributes Adjektiv, da "groß" in prädikativer Form vorliegt. Das andere (qualifizierend) gibt eher Auskunft darüber, "wie" das Nomen modifiziert wird. Während "groß" eine Eigenschaft zukommen lässt, ist "5" (quantifizierend) nur die Information, wie oft etwas vorkommt. In "Die fünf Bäume" ist "fünf" ein attributives quantifizierendes Adjektiv, jedoch nicht qualifizierend.

Comment: Ok, danke! Ich denke, ich habe nun verstanden, dass es zwei Paar Schuhe sind ;) Nur um sicher zu gehen: Die Formulierung "Sie konzentrieren sich auf qualifizierende Adjektive und auf Adjektive mit attributivem Gebrauch" wäre dann die entsprechende Aussage, die im Original "... attributive and descriptive adjectives" heißt?

Comment: Den gesamten englischen Satz (oder wenn kurz Text) zu kennen wäre von Vorteil, da die Übersetzung nach Kontext variieren könnte.

Comment: Es geht um Part-of-speech tags im Bereich Natural Language Processing. Konkreter geht es um eine Liste von Adjektiven, die als POS tag eine Eigenkreation der Autoren erhalten. Der Satz lautet "This tag subsumes attributive and descriptive adjectvices"